# I want to make a weather webpart that displays temperature by using Api like Google or yahoo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, xml, core-api

I want to make a Weather web part form any api. I have searched on Google but could not find any good solution. So, any link or suggestion or steps for that?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? With 2013's App Model, questions like this can be open to many different suggestions for solutions.

Comment: No,I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know how to build a basic web part? If not I suggest you learn this first. Here's a sample tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms415817(v=office.14).aspx

Next you want to learn how to develop against web services. Helpfully, Yahoo have a tutorial on how to deal with responses to web services as XML within C# applications: http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_cs.html. Yahoo have also documented their weather API: http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

Hopefully with these two fundamentals you know enough .NET development already to fill in the gaps.

Comment: can i use same code for web application,windows mobile also?

Comment: You can if you abstract out the code that gets the data from the web service, and structures it.

Comment: Thanks.james.Done.
but i want to ask one thing How can we Update Data of Curr. Temp in our Webart.

Comment: The best way you're going to want to do this is to have as much of the functionality of this in JavaScript - the web part emits JavaScript that will call the Yahoo API, process the returned result, and replace the area on screen with your processed & formatted results. If you do it this way, you can 'schedule' the whole process using JavaScript setTimeout() method, and have it repeat after a defined amount of time.